# Log In doesn't work after Abp .net core web app deployed to server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, abp

I use [Abp.io](https://abp.io/) framework and build .net core razor application including api.
It work perfectly on my localhost, but after I deploy to [smarterasp.net](https://www.smarterasp.net/), the login doesn't work anymore.
My URL is ,for example `http://mybackendportal-001-site1.btempurl.com/`.
I already change the appsetting of `App:SelfUrl` and `AuthServer:Authority` to above URL.
But still doesn't work, after login, it's redirect to login page again even the user name is password are correct, and no console error.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It has identity4 support. Check its configurations that it allows communication with the domain. Check also that the http protocol is the same as the one with the localhost. Check the network tab, if no errors are emitted, it is most likely to be a server side error. If no request is shown, with at least a response of 401, then it could be a client side problem. What client side technology do you use?

Comment: @LastGrip, I use razor view for client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using this reference [(How to fix the Chrome login issue for the IdentityServer4).](https://community.abp.io/posts/patch-for-chrome-login-issue-identityserver4-samesite-cookie-problem-weypwp3n)